# Javascript: Time and Info splitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

From server I get data as such:

```
"07.00 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION"
"07.20 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION 2"
```

I want to split them into a 2 indexed array such as: `["07.00", "PROGRAM DESCRIPTION 2"]`. Regular split( " " ) would not work me as the description part contains severaral " " spaces.

I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
var parts = str.split(' '),
    time = parts.shift(),
    description = parts.join(' ');
```

or, to get your array:

```
var parts = str.split(' ');
parts[1] = parts.slice(1).join(' ');
```

;)

Answer (score 2):

You need somekind of a pattern, which is reliable. If it's always the case that you need to split just between the first whitespace character to you can do:

```
var blub = "07.00 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION",
    pos  = blub.indexOf(" "),
    arr  = [];

arr[0] = blub.slice(0, pos);
arr[1] = blub.slice(pos + 1);
```

or you might just want to use regular expression. Since I don't pretend to be a genius on that field here is my little suggestion:

```
var blub = "07.00 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION",
    arr  = /(\d+\.\d+)\s(.*)/.exec(blub);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = /([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})\s(.+)/;
var data = "07.00 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION";
var parsed = pattern.exec(data);

console.log(parsed); // (Array) ["07.00 PROGRAM DESCRIPTION", "07.00", "PROGRAM DESCRIPTION"]
```

this is flexible and easier to adapt in case the format changes (just change the pattern and use that var anywhere else in your code)

Comment: further comment: for example in case the length of the time changes and becomes variable (i.e. 07.00 becomes 7:00, but it may be 19:00 too) you can make the pattern /([0-9]{1,2}(\.|:)[0-9]{2})\s(.+)/

Answer (score 0):

The substring method:

```
var time = row.substring(0,4);
var description = row.substring(5);
```

<strike>Or, with the split method:</strike>

```
row = row.split(" ",1);
```

The second parameter is the maximum number of splits... so it'll only split at the first space. **Edit:** this won't work. Use the first method instead.

Comment: Ah, I was going to +1 your split(" ", 1), but apparently that just discards the rest of the splits: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp :(